# Would it be possible to create your own semantic markup "<something></something>" for you template engine in PHP?

Tags: php

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me with this question :)

I want to know whether it's possible to create your own semantic markup in PHP, just like BB Codes, but I want to be able to use it within my template engine system, so I could use it to call custom modules like voting system, adding comments, login form, registration form and so on...

Let me make it clearer for you guys of how I mean;

I'm working on my own CMS not to use it for production purposes but to learn PHP in a better way;
So I had this idea to call specific modules in a page based on their position and in order to be able to do;

For instance we're having a login module which is simply a login form, nothing too crazy, however you want to be able to include that module dynamically in any page you want using the backend and not touching any code;

So all you do in the template page is using my bb codes that I told you earlier;
Something like this;

Remember this is only an idea;

```
<zone name="left_sidebar"></zone>
```

And you add this zone markup on your sidebar and if any of your module supposed to be displayed on your left sidebar, it will just by having this markup and nothing more...

And you gone have loads of these semantic markups based on how many editable blocks you have on your page; so you could have one for the right sidebar, one for footer and one for header... etc.

So I now need to know how to could lookup for opening and closing tags, in this case it would be `<zone></zone>` , then it need to lookup for its attribute and its value, in this case `name="right_sidevar"`
....

Anybody have any idea of how I could possibly do this kind of thing...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you seen Polymer (https://www.polymer-project.org/) yet?

Comment: No mate :( but I'll do it now :) Thx

Comment: As it seems, it's kind of difficult to accomplish such task in PHP, so I guess the best solution is create those zones bases on classes and functions that calls accordingly if I'm not wrong... so something like this I guess would be closest solution....   $zone->position('left_sidebar');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out TWIG; while it doesn't directly support this kind of feature (because it uses a special syntax for its own elements) it does have *very* good support for making your own elements, tags, sub-applications and other funky things in the backend.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

There are also a number of systems that perform this kind of task in the front-end; this would mean that the substitution is done by Javascript in the browser. In addition to the already mentioned Polymer, there's also Google's framework, Angular.

https://angularjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately front-end solution can not be considered as 1) isn't safe enough, 2) what if js was not enabled... also it's always a good practice to leave the front-end stuff away from back-end as I'm sure u gone run into trouble somewhere down the line... Thx

Comment: Keep in mind that TWIG isn't frontend. You should really look into that one, it can accomplish what you want, although it might look slightly different from what you expect right now.

Comment: Yes sure! I'll look into it :), but by front-end I meant AngularJS... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use php's libxml module to parse your xml file.